# Creating CURL Request ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, curl, webrequest

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC053acaaf55d75ef32233132196e/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=5555555555'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+15555555555'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Test' \
-u AC053acaaf55d75a393498192382196e:[AuthToken]
```

I have the above curl code for an API I need to connect to. The problem is I need to connect using ASP.NET (C#). I'm not very familiar with ASP.NET and don't really know where to begin. I know how to code this in PHP but ASP.NET is another matter. From the research I've done I need to use WebRequest. How do I feed in the post data and the authtoken (-u AC053acaaf55d75a393498192382196e:[AuthToken])  part of the request.

```
string url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC053acaaf55d75ef32233132196e/Messages.json";
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.Method = "POST";
```

Comment: What does "need to connect" mean? what function are you trying to perform?

Comment: Sorry, basically I need to create a post/curl request to this url. It's for a text messaging service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to make sure we are on the same page, you need to make a POST request to theMessages endpoint in the Twilio API, but you cannot use our helper library.

Not a problem, you can just use .NETs native HTTP client libraries, HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.  Thats going to look something like this:

```
//Twilio Credentials
string accountsid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
string authtoken = "asdsadasdasdasdasdsadsaads";

//Twilio API url, putting your AccountSid in the URL
string urltemplate = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{0}/Messages.json";
string url = string.Format(urltemplate, accountsid);

//Create a basic authorization
string basicauthtoken = string.Format("Basic {0}", System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accountsid + ":" + authtoken)));

//Build and format the HTTP POST data
string formencodeddata = "To=+15555555555&From=+15556666666&Body=Hello World";
byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(formencodeddata);

//Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicauthtoken);

using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream()) {
    postStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
}

//Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream
var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

There are also async versions of the GetRequestStream and GetResponse methods if you need them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that is what I referring too. However, when I run the code I get a 400 bad request error. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: I got it working, I just had to add webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; after webrequest.Method = "POST"; If you edit your code I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @devin-rader is this answer still valid? Because I am getting 400 Bad Request

Comment: @FaizanRabbani yes, this is still valid.  The body of the 400 response should have details on what was bad about the request.

Comment: System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes is omitting "+" symbol, due to which I was getting not valid To number error, I had to use HttpUtility.UrlEndcode to properly encode + symbol to %2B

Comment: Does anyone know why it would get stuck on this line: var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has some great docs for this here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls
they also have a great c# library here; twilio.com/docs/csharp/install but here's an example in C# showing how to make a call.

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "AC3094732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659";
    string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var options = new CallOptions();
    options.Url = "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml";
    options.To = "+14155551212";
    options.From = "+14158675309";
    var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

    Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);    
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually can't connect to Twilio C# api. For this particular project I am working on I cannot add anymore Dlls so I need to connect to their cURL api directly.

Answer (score 0):

Working code for me

string accountsid = "AccountSid";
            string authtoken = "AuthToken";

```
        //Twilio API url, putting your AccountSid in the URL
        string urltemplate = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{0}/Messages.json";
        string url = string.Format(urltemplate, accountsid);
```

//Get Client Secret and client key from the API Keys section-- https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api
            string basicauthtoken = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("ClientSecret:ClientKey"));

```
        //Build and format the HTTP POST data
        string formencodeddata = "To={To}&From={From}&Body={Body}";
        byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(formencodeddata);

        //Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
        var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicauthtoken);

        using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
        }

        //Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream
        var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Macshaw, do you know why it would get stuck on this line: var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();